# SNMPGET works from program but not from CLI

Tags: snmp, fax, samsung

I am working on an fax grabber, for a fax in our building only Samsung provides the software "Samsung Easy Printer Manager" the program sends an SNMPGET to the Printer as I saw in Wireshark

```
Frame 133: 89 bytes on wire (712 bits), 89 bytes captured (712 bits) on interface bridge102, id 5
Ethernet II, Src: Parallel_53:1e:29 (Mac), Dst: SamsungE_69:6f:fe (Mac)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.178.125, Dst: 192.168.178.38
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 55160, Dst Port: 161
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: version-1 (0)
    community: Test
    data: get-request (0)
        get-request
            request-id: 10944
            error-status: noError (0)
            error-index: 0
            variable-bindings: 1 item
                1.3.6.1.4.1.236.11.5.11.81.12.16.1.2.1: Value (Null)
                    Object Name: 1.3.6.1.4.1.236.11.5.11.81.12.16.1.2.1 (iso.3.6.1.4.1.236.11.5.11.81.12.16.1.2.1)
                    Value (Null)
    [Response To: 134]
    [Time: 0.000019000 seconds]
```

Answer:

```
Frame 135: 93 bytes on wire (744 bits), 93 bytes captured (744 bits) on interface vmenet2, id 2
Ethernet II, Src: SamsungE_69:6f:fe (Mac), Dst: Parallel_53:1e:29 (Mac)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.178.38, Dst: 192.168.178.125
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 161, Dst Port: 55160
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: version-1 (0)
    community: Test
    data: get-response (2)
        get-response
            request-id: 10944
            error-status: noError (0)
            error-index: 0
            variable-bindings: 1 item
                1.3.6.1.4.1.236.11.5.11.81.12.16.1.2.1: 01000000
                    Object Name: 1.3.6.1.4.1.236.11.5.11.81.12.16.1.2.1 (iso.3.6.1.4.1.236.11.5.11.81.12.16.1.2.1)
                    Value (OctetString): 01000000
    [Response To: 134]
    [Time: 0.012747000 seconds]
```

But if im sending the get Request from my Laptop I get:

> SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.236.11.5.11.81.12.16.1.2.1 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID

and after i googled the OID there was no result.
Any Ideas

Comment: From Wireshark, what did you send exactly? Compare it to the one sent by "Samsung Easy Printer Manager" and focus on the differences.

Comment: can you include the exact command you used on your laptop?

Comment: i figured it out, i think the printer is changing the OID from 0-5 as a new device connects via http request.